# I want to receive a JSON (sendend by POST method of JS xmlHttpRequest()) echo from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

The code JS is

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
//console.log(xhr)

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4){
        console.log(xhr)
    }
}

xhr.open("POST","https://testepr.harpiastudios.com.br/http-receiver.php")
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

function sendText(text){
    let dataToSend = {
        "text": text
    }

   

    console.log(dataToSend)
    xhr.send(dataToSend)
}
```

and the PHP Code is:

```
$dataToSend = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    

    
echo($dataToSend->text);
```

The php file returns
**Notice**: Trying to get property of non-object in

I need to echo this value cause i need to use for other things. I dont know to have acces from this index of JSON

Comment: Where are you using the sendText function?

Comment: Also, you're preparing your xhr to recieve JSON response, but echo $json->text will not give you a proper JSON response. That `echo` might just be for testing, just wanted to let you know

Comment: The main issue here seems to be that you're not actually sending any JSON. Run JSON.stringify on your JS object before you send it

Comment: You are not sending a JSON as response, you cannot send a decoded data, you can only send JSON encoded data.